# How to print the value of a web element in console?

Tags: javascript

I have a web element which I have found css selector for and now I want to print its value in console. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following:

```
<input id="myValue" type="textbox" value="foo bar">
```

You can log the value like so:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myValue');
console.log(elem.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by `value`

In html these tags will have value attribute

```
<button>, <option>, <input>, <li>, <meter>, <progress>, <param>
```

For example

```
<button type="button" value="1" id="myButton">My button</button>
```

Here you can use a `id` selector(or any other relevant selector) to get the DOM element

```
var _getValue = document.getElementById('myButton').value; // will give 1
```

Now use [**console.log**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) like `console.log(_getValue)` which will log the value in console of developer's tool

If your looking for text inside element like `span` you have to do [**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or `textContent` to get the text

```
<span id ="myspan"> My Span </span>
var _getValue = document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML;
console.log(_getValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fetched the element by:
 `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("classNameHere");` you'll have an array of HTML elements. Extract the first element:`x = x[0];` than get the content by `console.log(x.innerHTML());`
If your element is an input use `console.log(x.value)` to get the value.